# Splitting data from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

So I have a dataset and I am trying to split the data into 4 lists. I have written this function to do just that.

```
def __spit_list_into_group(self, IDList, n, list1, list2, list3, list4):
    newlist = [IDList[i:i + n] for i in xrange(0, len(IDList), n)]
    list1, list2, list3, list4 = map(list, zip(*newlist))

    return list1, list2, list3, list4
```

However, when I set `n` to be 4, the code is only able to split the data into 3 lists and when I set `n` to be 5, the code splits it to 5 lists. Why doesn't the code split the data into 4 and how can i get it to split the data into 4?

EDIT: I realized that this dataset has 15 data points which is why I am only able to split it into 3 and 5. How do I split the data into 4, not necessarily, equal groups? I need to write something that is flexible as I want the same code to work on other data sets which may have more or less data points.

Comment: by the way in this case, you don't need to pass `list1, list2, list3, list4`. Just passing `self, IDList, n` will be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be simplified by using index slicing.

If you want to create `n` lists of roughly equal size you can do this:

```
def split_list(input_list, n):
    output_lists = [input_list[i::n] for i in range(n)]
    return output_lists
```

This steps through your input list in jumps of `n` to give the required number of output lists.

For example, say your input list is `range(15)`, or `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]` and you want `n=4` lists.
This will return `[[0,4,8,12],[1,5,9,13],[2,6,10,14],[3,7,11]]`.

Alternatively, if you want to group the input list into `n` output lists, preserving the original order, you could do:

```
import math

def split_list(input_list, n):
    group_size = int(math.ceil(len(input_list)/float(n)))
    output_lists = [input_list[group_size*i:min((i+1)*group_size, len(input_list))] for i in range(n)]
    return output_lists
```

Using the same example as above, this will return `[[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11],[12,13,14]]`.

Comment: Ahh. I see. Thanks!

Comment: I added the expected outcome. It just depends on whether the order is important or not.

Comment: I made a few edits to the code to make it work more generally for any `input_list` size and `n`.

Comment: Mmm. I don't quite understand. How does that edit make the code more general?

Comment: When I tried the original code on different size input arrays it didn't always work. This version should.

Comment: I see. Thanks! I shall try it out too

Answer (score 1):

This is because the length of your `IDList` list is not divisable by `4`, leaving a sub-list in `newlist` with 3 items only, and when you `zip` the sub-lists, the zipping stops when any one of the input iterators is exhausted, resulting in only 3 lists instead of 4. You can replace `zip` with `itertools.izip_longest` instead (after importing `itertools`) so the output would be as expected.